# Regular Expression Bracket Expression with bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, special-characters

I want to write a regular expression that only allows a user to enter an input which contains alphanumeric characters, underscores, periods, dashes, and plus signs.

In a bash script, I have:

```
VALID="^[0-9a-zA-Z_\.\-\+]+$"
THE_INPUT=$1
if [[ ! $THE_INPUT =~ $VALID ]]; then
    echo "ERROR"
    exit 1  
fi
```

Why does this not work when the user enters an input which has a - in it?

Example user inputs:

1. great-food.png

   i. produces error
2. great_+food.png

   i. doesn't produce error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[0-9a-zA-Z_\.\-\+]` bracket expression in POSIX Basic or Extended¹ regular expressions matches:

- `0-9`: collating elements (not even necessarily single characters!) ranging between `0` and `9` (could be anything depending on the locale, so that should not be used for input validation outside the `C`/`POSIX` locale)
- `a-zA-Z`: same for `a` to `z` and `A` to `Z`.
- `_\.`: either underscore, backslash or period:
- `\-\`: collating elements sorting between `\` and `\`. Likely only `\` but you never know.
- `\+`: backslash again and `+`.

As `\` is not special inside bracket expressions.

To include a literal `-` in the set, it needs to be placed last or first (or right after `^` in negated sets).

bash uses POSIX Extended regexps for its `=~` operator.

Here, you'd want:

```
VALID='^[0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_.+-]+$'
```

If switching to `zsh` is an option, you could use its extended glob operators which are a superset of extended regexps with a different syntax and behave less surprisingly, and can work with non-text contrary to regexps:

```
set -o extendedglob
VALID='[0-9a-zA-Z_+.-]##'

if [[ $input != $~VALID ]]; then...
```

(note the `~` for the contents of `$VALID` to be taken as a pattern here instead of literally).

It also has a `[:WORD:]` character class that matches any character classified as `alnum` in the locale plus the ones in `$WORDCHARS`.

In the C locale, you could define `WORDCHARS='.-+_'` and then use:

```
set -o extendedglob # needed for ##, the equivalent of ERE +.
VALID='[[:WORD:]]##'
```

`zsh` also has support for PCREs which also have non-surprising bracket expressions:

```
zmodload zsh/pcre
VALID='^[0-9a-zA-Z._+-]+\z'

if [[ ! $input -pcre-match $VALID ]]; then...
```

Or make `=~` use PCRE instead of ERE:

```
set -o rematchpcre
VALID='^[0-9a-zA-Z._+-]+\z'

if [[ ! $input =~ $VALID ]]; then...
```

You could also use `VALID='^[0-9a-zA-Z\-._+]+\z'` there.

Beware that PCRE doesn't support multibyte charsets other than UTF-8, and the above reports errors in UTF-8 locales if `$input` is not valid UTF-8.

In the C locale, you could also use `VALID='^[\w.+-]\z'`, where `\w` matches `alnum`s and underscore.

---

<sup>¹ awk being an exception as it does use extended regexps but `\` is still special within bracket expressions or [at least it is in some implementations](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1105).</sup>

Comment: What is a "locale" in the context of regex?

Comment: @user3731622, see `man 7 locale` on your system for instance. Here for regexp, what matters are the `LC_CTYPE` category including the charmap which determines how sequence of bytes are decoded into text and the character classifications (alpha, digit, alnum as used in `[[:alnum:]]`, `\w` or zsh's `[[:WORD:]]`), and the `LC_COLLATE` category that defines how text is collated (that the `㎉` character sorts somewhere between `k` and `l` or that the `ddzs` collating element sorts between `d` and `e` in a `hu_HU` Hungarian locale for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Usually in a regex, the `-` character in a character class block implies a range (e. g. `[a-z]`.  The usual way to express that you are *not* meaning to imply a range is to put the hyphen at the very end of the character class descriptor.  When I do so in your script, it seems to work as you wish:

```
VALID="^[0-9a-zA-Z_\.\+\-]+$"
```

Thus:

```
$ ./741634.sh parameter/with/slashes
ERROR
$ ./741634.sh parameter-with-dashes
$
```

Comment: And you shouldn't need to escape any of those characters unless you want backslash to be part of the expression.